# Devise logout when trying to update item only on firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, firefox, heroku, devise

I have a strange issue with my app:
When i try to update an item i'm signed out by devise unexpectedly just after the PUT. 
More strange this is **only happening on Firefox** and in production. 
On all others browsers i don't have any problems and in dev i don't have problems even on firefox.

[Here is the edit form template](http://pastebin.com/mnbmrPCw)

Thanks for your answers and forgive me for my poor english.

Nicolas

Comment: Log from heroku is not really helpful. Could you please attach development.lo excerpt?

Comment: Sorry first time for me ;) it also perfectly work in development... so no errors in dev logs

Comment: But there's no error in this log either. Can you show the form you use?

Comment: question edited with form template

Comment: Are you able to use Firefox on an different computer to isolate if it's a Firefox issue versus a local issue.

Comment: Hi @JohnBeynon, it's already done. My app is online and all my customers using firefox have the same problem, regardless the version of ff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing file uploads, as a security feature you need to pass the CSRF Token with the upload, the way I did this was to put this in the head of my layouts/application.html.erb file

```
# layouts/application.html.erb
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Then in the URL your uploading to, pass the CSRF Token as a param

```
var csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
var csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content');

if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
  upload_params = csrf_param + "=" + encodeURIComponent(csrf_token);
}
```